# Discord Bot python TypeError: string indices must be integers

Tags: python, discord.py, pycord

This in the beginning hard problem was in the end easy fixed :)

Comment: You have to share more code. Anyway from what you have given here, it seems like `settings` is not what you are expecting.

Comment: Where does it set the value in `settings` variable? If you have, please share that.

Comment: I have given an answer, please check that. But do you have a documentation link or something? that `settings =` line is what's causing the error. Settings currently has a string inside it and not a list. So it fails with the error you mentioned in the post.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to do slice operation in string.
example:

```
>>> a
'string'

>>> a[0]
's'

>>> a["s"]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: string indices must be integers
>>>
```

hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how this works. But if you have a settings.json file and that file is there in the directory where this py file exists, then the below code should work.

```
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='/', intents=discord.Intents.all())
settings = None
with open("./settings.json", "r") as settings_file:
    data = settings_file.read()
    settings = json.loads(data)
```

Comment: @AriV there was a typo in the answer. Can you please replace the line `settings = json.load(data)` with `settings = json.loads(data)`